# How to solve problems occured while trying to launch excelsior jet11

Tags: launching

I installed Excelsior Jet11 and trying to use it. I downloaded it from their official site. I also exported the paths also with the followings.

```
export PATH=JET-home/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\
JET-home/lib/x86/shared:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I specified the  with the directory of jet. I also activated the profile that is supported by jet. But while i'm trying to launch JET with this: `../../opt/jet11/profile1.8.0_40/jre/bin/java`
returned a message like following image without launching the JET.
[image: Message Screen Shot]
I'm not getting any solution now to launch it.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a sentence about what Excelsior Jet is - I had to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to launch *your app* with that:

```
../../opt/jet11/profile1.8.0_40/jre/bin/java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Alternatively, type

```
jetcp
```

to bring up the Excelsior JET Control Panel.